# Is it *incorrect* to use single digit numerals?

Tags: grammar, written-language, numbers, numerals

I had an argument with someone recently and figured I should find out, so I went on a research spree and could not find any authoritative answers on the subject.

I am sure there are many disputes about how one should write numbers, as digits (0-9) or as words (one, two, three....)

I just want to know about one particular subset of this.

If I want to write `'Three cookies'` is it ***incorrect*** to write `'3 cookies'`?

Context:

I am aware that when wanting to write *large* numbers, it is acceptable to write with digits, like in the case of `'4356 people showed up to the event'` since it would be sort of silly to write `'four thousand three hundred and fifty six people showed up to the event'` but in the case of *single* digits, I was always told I should write the number out fully, and not just use the digit.

I hope my question is clear, I do not want to start a discussion or a debate about anything other than the particular case of writing a *single* digit versus writing out the word. Thanks.

Comment: Hey @Inbar Rose, this would probably be a question that would be better placed in the English Language and Usage stack exchange, as it's more of a question about style, rather than linguistics.

Comment: I thought so at first, but then I figured, this is not solely an 'English' issue. I myself speak three languages (3 languages?) and it can easily apply to all of them.

Comment: I suppose you have a point there

Comment: Asking this question about different languages may solicit a debate or variety of equally correct answers.

Comment: I don't see the Linguistic question in this... To me it sounds like a style-related question (regardless of the language). I agree with Danger on that.

Comment: Inbar, your question has been closed as Off Topic because it's not really a Linguistic question. Note that you can improve it (if you manage to make it on topic, we'll reopen it) and that the -1 is automatic because of the closure. :)

Comment: Just a tip--the terms "correct" and "incorrect" are going to raise red flags here (regardless of the language or languages under consideration), because such terms are outside the purview of linguistics. Linguists are interested in _descriptive_ grammar, i.e. how people speak in real life, not _prescriptive_ grammar, i.e. how rulebooks, style guides, and high school English (or whatever language) teachers say people should speak or write.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is wholly in the purview of style guides, which is the only domain in which this can be 'incorrect'. Many such guides agree that sentences should not begin with numerals, and it is common to prescribe that numbers <10 should be written out. If you're writing for a publication (in whatever language), you should follow their rules.

Comment: I'm simply curious. Since the written word is something that comes after the spoken word, it has more rules, when speaking this issue never arises, and I am just wondering.